# How to prepend directory locations in python script?

Tags: python

I probably will have 3 questions on this file but for now I will focus on the problem, not the addition i need to make. I have a script that is working perfectly to create a json file of directory contents. The problem I have is on line 9. The output it is giving me is correct, however the directory path is not loading correctly in the audio player application because the directory paths needs prepended with ../audio/

Here is the script:

```
import os
import errno

def path_hierarchy(path):
    hierarchy = {
       # 'name': os.path.basename(path),
        'artist': os.path.basename(path),
        'album': 'Node 42177',
        'url': os.path.basename(path),  # HERE!
        'cover_art_url': '../album-art/Radio.jpg',
    }

    try:
        hierarchy['children'] = [
            path_hierarchy(os.path.join(path, contents))
            for contents in os.listdir(path)
        ]
    except OSError as e:
        if e.errno != errno.ENOTDIR:
            raise
        #hierarchy['type'] = 'file'

    return hierarchy

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import json
    import sys

    try:
        directory = sys.argv[1]
    except IndexError:
        directory = "."

    print(json.dumps(path_hierarchy(directory), indent=2, sort_keys=True))
```

I have tried everything I can think of to insert the ../audio/ at the beginning of the url string but keep getting errors. Could anyone tell me the syntax needed please?

Comment: Is `"../audio/" + path` not working for some reason, or `os.path.join("..", "audio", os.path.basename(path))`? Note that line numbers are really not very helpful, because StackOverflow doesn't show them to us - if you make a comment in the code that indicates where the issue is, it would be clearer

Comment: Try `os.path.join("../audio/", os.path.basename(path))`

Comment: What have you tried that is not working? Can you add a [mcve] to the question focused on the question you are asking?

Comment: wwii I tried 'url': "../audio/"os.path.basename(path), 
I tried 'url': '../audio/'os.path.basename(path), 
I tried 'url': '../audio/'+os.path.basename(path), 

Green Cloak Guy thank you for the tip on line numbers vs. StackOverflow, I did not know this. Your first solution worked great, the second gave a few errors. Thank you.

Rakeesh yours also worked great, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `os.path.join`

**Ex:**

```
hierarchy = {
       # 'name': os.path.basename(path),
        'artist': os.path.basename(path),
        'album': 'Node 42177',
        'url': os.path.join("../audio/", os.path.basename(path)),
        'cover_art_url': '../album-art/Radio.jpg',
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

In line 9, in order to prepend, you have to call the os.path inside os.joi as in the following example:

```
'url': os.path.join("..","audio",os.path.basename(path))
```

It will give you:

```
"url": "..\\audio\\path"
```

Another suggestion is to change this part:

```
hierarchy['children'] = [
        path_hierarchy(os.path.join(path, contents))
        for contents in os.listdir(path)
    ]
```

for this:

```
hierarchy['children'] = [
        path_hierarchy(os.path.join(path, contents))
        for contents in os.listdir(path)
        if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(path, contents))
    ]
```

If you intend to take only directories, this 'if' will allow the loop ignore files.